# How to get data for same dates using moment?

Tags: javascript, typescript, momentjs

I have below method is that is returning true if dates are inBetween but i also want to return true if dates are equal i to start/end date , is it possible to do that with moment ?

main.ts

```
function checkDateRange(startDate: string, endDate: string, fillDate: string): boolean {
    if (fillDate > startDate && fillDate < endDate) {
        const _fillDate = moment(fillDate).utc();
        return _fillDate.isBetween(startDate, endDate);
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't the first step be to parse the string params into moment dates?  After that, moment provides a few ways to handle equality and inequality, including diff-ing, isBefore, isSame, isAfter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the function returns a boolean, just return the value of the conditional test.  !before and !after is the same as in-between, inclusive...

```
function checkDateRange(startDateStr: string, endDateStr: string, fillDateStr: string): boolean {
    let startDate = moment(startDateStr);
    let endDate = moment(endDateStr);
    let fillDate = moment(fillDateStr);

    return !fillDate.isBefore(startDate) && !fillDate.isAfter(endDate)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add inclusivity parameter to [`isBetween`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/query/is-between/):

> Version **2.13.0** introduces inclusivity. A `[` indicates inclusion of a value. A `(` indicates exclusion.
>   If the inclusivity parameter is used, both indicators must be passed.
>
> If the inclusivity parameter is not specified, Moment will default to `()`.

You code could be like the following:

```
function checkDateRange(startDate: string, endDate: string, fillDate: string): boolean {
    if (fillDate > startDate && fillDate < endDate) {
        const _fillDate = moment(fillDate).utc();
        return _fillDate.isBetween(startDate, endDate, null, '[]');
    }

    return false;
}
```